# Não consigo encontrar maneira de remover o espaçamento do meu CSS

Tags: javascript, html, css, scss

Eu voltei recentemente a tentar desenvolver a minha aprendizagem em web development e tentei desenvolver um curriculo online para eventualmente trabalhar na área. Como não sou muito bom em CSS ainda, fiz o download dum template no https://startbootstrap.com/themes/resume/

Eu não fiz alterações no meu site no CSS mas o site em mobile está completamente diferente do meu lado.

A versão no computador está perfeita, não tenho queixas. A versão mobile vista no meu telemóvel, que devia estar [assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFNu5.png), vista pelo telemóvel está [assim](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OoATn.jpg). O meu telemóvel é um samsung s8+.

Estou a usar os mesmos ficheiros CSS e SCSS, a estrutura é a mesma, queria tentar compreender o porquê da minha versão ser diferente daquela que é mostrada no site de download do template.

Para efeitos de teste, eu hospedei uma versão do template no 000webhost.com e foi assim que encontrei o meu problema.

Desde já obrigado.